# OS X Harddrive locking me out

Tags: hard-drive, macos, login

I am trying to log into my mac (OS X Yosemite) but it keeps showing me this:

[image]

I can't even go to recovery mode because when I hold option after rebooting, the only thing that comes up is "Macintosh HD" (My partition name).

So I installed El Capitan on a USB (from another computer) and used the recovery thing in there and it doesn't even show the Macintosh HD in there even though it's there when I hold the option key.

My Mac installation has to be there because when it boots up, I can see my background and my profile picture to login. I don't understand what's going on, please help me. I don't want to lose all my files.

Comment: That icon is called the **prohibitory sign**. When running from the USB, what does it show in Disk Utility?

Comment: @IronCraftMan It shows this: http://i.imgur.com/7OlhMPw.jpg

Comment: Under internal > disk0s4, what does it say?

Comment: disk0s4 is just an empty partition, doesn't say anything. I verified the disk and it says no problems found.

Comment: how big is it? It might be your Macintosh HD.

Comment: It's only 50GB. My mac was 200gb.

Comment: why is there a 50GB partition on your hard drive? Is it for Boot Camp? Additional storage?

Comment: It was for Ubuntu. I erased it though, I think that might have had something to do with this problem but I don't understand how or why.

Comment: please include those details in your question. How did you erase it and when?